# Allowing Users to Delete Their Posts

Tags: posts

I'm trying to allow users to delete their posts, and I'm trying to do that with the;

```
$or_pid = get_the_ID();
if(isset($_REQUEST['p_id']) && $_REQUEST['p_id']>0){
        wp_delete_post($_REQUEST['p_id']);

}
```

and

```
<div class="tbl_col"><a class="delt" href="<?php echo get_permalink($or_pid); ?>&p_id=<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">Delete</a></div>
        </div>
```

but it's not working. You check the whole code from http://pastebin.com/VWN21GNZ
I'd be grateful if you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what "it's not working" you mean. It gives error or what?
Maybe you should echo $_REQUEST['p_id'] first before delete it, just make sure you got the request. Or create a variable to store wp_delete_post and check if it works or not.

Comment: When I try to delete a post, it directs me to "/image-list/&p_id=1035" or whatever id number of that post is. And the post remains still and I get a 404 error.

Comment: change & with ?